# Using Location updates affects the main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-location, android-handler

I am using the following code to request for location updates. The location updates are requested in a separate handler thread but still it affects the main thread. Can anyone please suggest a solution.

```
private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mBearing = location.getBearing();

        }
}


mLocationManager = (LocationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();

Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();

mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    UPDATE_LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                                    UPDATE_LOCATION_MINIMUM_DISTANCE,
                                    mLocationListener, looper);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    UPDATE_LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                                    UPDATE_LOCATION_MINIMUM_DISTANCE,
                                    mLocationListener, looper);
```

Comment: How do you know it affects the main thread?

Comment: I am using the main thread to receive video over the network, it gets affected. It works fine when I disable location updates, but starts to fail with location updates.

Comment: "I am using the main thread to receive video over the network" -- that's bad on its own. Do not do network I/O on the main application thread. You should be crashing with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: To be more accurate, there is a listener, that listens for video chunks in the main thread. The socket connection, receive are handled in a different thread, not in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue seems to be that the looper isn't ready when you call `Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();`.  This ends up making the `looper` null, which causes the location updates to occur on the main thread.  Here is some more info on the [getLooper()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#getLooper()) function.  Try this:

```
public class LocationThread extends HandlerThread {

    private static final long UPDATE_LOCATION_INTERVAL = 0;  //Set this to whatever you had it at
    private static final float UPDATE_LOCATION_MINIMUM_DISTANCE = 0.0f;  //Same with this

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;

    public LocationThread(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    //Pass in your location manager and listener to this.  This assumes they are not null!
    public void startLocationUpdates(LocationManager locationManager, LocationListener locationListener){
        mLocationManager = locationManager;
        mLocationListener = locationListener;
        start();
    }

    //Use this to stop the updates and kill the thread.
    public void stopLocationUpdates(){
        if(mLocationManager != null){
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
            mLocationListener = null;
            mLocationManager = null;
        }

        quit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                        UPDATE_LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                                        UPDATE_LOCATION_MINIMUM_DISTANCE,
                                        mLocationListener, getLooper());
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                        UPDATE_LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                                        UPDATE_LOCATION_MINIMUM_DISTANCE,
                                        mLocationListener, getLooper());
    }
}
```

For this class, do not use the `start()` or `quit()` functions, since they are already in use internally.